How do I use cumulative data to show an hourly total?
I'm logging data from my gas meter using rtlamr to InfluxDB 1.6.7. The gas meter periodically transmits its consumption in a running total, so it looks like this (for example):
100
100
101
101
102
105
105

It doesn't transmit at a fixed time interval. It just occasionally chooses to emit a value usually every few minutes.
When plotting this data in Grafana, how can I instead see total consumption grouped by hour rather than an ever-increasing running total? I've seen some examples, but they're for InfluxDB v2 which I can't use.

You can try the following InfluxQL query for a Grafana panel:
SELECT DIFFERENCE(last("consumption")) AS "hourly_consumption" 
FROM "gas_meter" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time(1h) 
FILL(0)

It calculate the difference using DIFFERENCE function between each time interval grouped hourly. FILL function ensures any data is reported as zero consumption.

Thanks, that worked after tweaking for my setup:

